# Server 2012r2 change login screen language with registry

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-registry

I am installing a Windows Server 2012R2 RDS farm. The OS language is English, but my users are Dutch.

I already installerd the Dutch MUI pack in windows via the command prompt. Via a user GPO  the user is forced interface to be Dutch.

However, when a user logs on, the first few messages and the login screen are still in English. I know I can change this via control panel to make current settings "default for all new users". However, this is a manual operation and I want it to be set this way automatically.

Is there some way to do this with a GPO/registry key? I tried changing 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages\nl-NL >> DefaultFallback to "nl-NL" but that does not work.

Someone any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

These are suggestions, I haven't had to tackle this myself...
1) BCDBoot sounds the most promising, and may be the only thing necessary.

```
bcdboot %WinDir% /l nl-NL
```

2) Are these machines being built with an answer file?
This says language can be specfied in the answer file.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744569%28WS.10%29.aspx

3) Before a use logs in, settings are derived from HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT hive.
You might try some of these:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\MuiCached\MachinePreferredUILanguages
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\sLanguage
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\448\52C64B7E\LanguageList
```

4) GPO has some "override" options, but it sounds a little overkill for this case. These would need to be set in a GPO linked to the OU the computer account resides in.
Computer Config/Windows Settings/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Regional and Language Options